# Icecast2 private stream with django website

Tags: django, icecast, internet-radio

I have a django website i stream on my website with icecast 2 server with the link `http://ip number:port number/mount` but if any one use this link he can use my radio i want to make my radio work on my website only

Comment: You need to authentication listeners somehow.  Icecast has built-in easy support for basic auth.  Beyond that, you can use the URL based authentication mechanism:  http://www.icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/auth.html#listener_add

Comment: I built a simple Django project that is doing exactly what you need. It also handles users registration and streams notifications. I just added a feature to include Discogs release metadata in the stream information. I must say it's not a complete site yet and a lot of development needs to be done, but if you want to take a look it's here https://gitlab.com/simonepozzoli/songspotting/